# An I use an element attribute on a Route component so that the ID is not necessary?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**App.jsx**

```
<Route path="/cart/:id?" element={<CartScreen />} />
```

In React-router-v6 can I still use this so that the id parameter is not always necessary?
if it exists it goes to the "CartScreen" component
if it doesn't exist it also goes to the "CartScreen"

Comment: The route path looks fine to me. Are you just asking if it's possible or have you tried it and have an actual issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**React Router v6.5+**

Yes, the above code will work. Although not originally supported in version 6, it has been reintroduced in recent updates.

**React Router v6.0-6.4**

Optional params are not supported. Instead, you must create two separate routes:

```
<Route path="/cart/" [...]>
<Route path="/cart/:id" [...]>
```

Comment: React Router v6 ***does*** actually support [optional path segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#optional-segments). This code will *technically* work, but the answer isn't 100% correct and reasoning is a bit misleading.

Comment: Ah, I see that this has been updated in version 6.5 - I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for the callout!